# Print lines starting with an even number

Tags: regex, grep, numbers

I have the following input,

```
10
12    a
12 a
14a
```

The following command

```
sed -rn '/^[0-9]*[02468]\s/p'
```

(or an equivalent grep command) returns

```
12    a   
12 a
```

only and not 10 because there is an EOL following 10. On the other hand, if I drop the \s, 14a is also returned, which is not a number.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 1):

With given data, here are commands that would give you expected results.

**`search & replacement:`**

```
sed -rn '/^[0-9]*[02468] |^[0-9]*[02468]$|^[0-9]*[02468]\t/p' n.txt

sed -rn 's/^[0-9]*[02468] |^[0-9]*[02468]$|^[0-9]*[02468]\t/blah/p' n.txt
```

**`search & replacement using awk`:**

```
awk -F" " '{if ($1 ~ /[02468]$/ && $1 % 2 == 0) print $1}' n.txt

awk -F" " '{if ($1 ~ /[02468]$/ && $1 % 2 == 0) print gensub($1,"blah", 1); else print $0;}' n.txt
```

`NOTE:` line 10 has nothing after 10, line 12 has space after 12 and line 16 has tab after 16.

Sample Run

```
[/c]$ cat n.txt
10
11
12 a
13
14a
16      

[/c]$ sed -rn '/^[0-9]*[02468] |^[0-9]*[02468]$|^[0-9]*[02468]\t/p' n.txt
10
12 a
16

[/c]$ sed -rn 's/^[0-9]*[02468] |^[0-9]*[02468]$|^[0-9]*[02468]\t/blah/p' n.txt
blah
blaha
blah
```

Sample Run(with awk)

```
[/c]$ cat n.txt
10
11
12 a this is spaced line
13
14a
16      this is tab line

[/c]$ awk -F" " '{if ($1 ~ /[02468]$/ && $1 % 2 == 0) print $0}' n.txt
10
12 a this is spaced line
16      this is tab line

[/c]$ awk -F" " '{if ($1 ~ /[02468]$/ && $1 % 2 == 0) print gensub($1,"blah", 1); else print $0;}' n.txt
blah
11
blah a this is spaced line
13
14a
blah    this is tab line
```

Comment: Good point. I should have made clear I do NOT want the line with 14a to be returned, because it's not an even number.

Comment: Nice. I replaced the " " in your code with \s to allow tabs, etc.

Comment: glad to help, I have updated my answer to include regex for tabs too. Hope you can vote up or accept my answer.

Comment: For more complex patterns than an "even number", is there a way to avoid having to type the pattern twice, once with a \s, and once with a $?

Comment: without extended regex it would be difficult. Also for tabs, i had to use \t and not \s

Comment: \s worked for me for both spaces and tabs. Would an extended regexp solution be compatible with sed?

Comment: Few examples : http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html & https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html

Comment: Great! Edited original post to remove required for basic regexp. What would be an extended regexp solution?

Comment: I have updated solution with and without extended regex.

Comment: I'm afraid extended regexp version still returns 14a, which is not a number.

Comment: for search try, awk -F" " '{if ($1 ~ /[02468]$/ && $1 % 2 == 0) print $1}' n.txt

Comment: FYI - I have reverted my extended regex as they weren't working, so now you can search and replace with `sed` alone.

Comment: Another good solution! For more complex patterns, awk may be better. Btw, in your code, why not replace (" " or $ or "\t") with ($ or "\s")?

Comment: added awk to the solution for search

Comment: After playing around with `awk`, I found how to replace using `awk`. Updated the solution with `awk` for replacement also.

Answer (score 0):

Allow an EOL instead of further characters.

```
$ sed -rn '/^[0-9]*[02468](\s|$)/p' < data
10
12    a
12 a
```